# Disallow passing more parameters to a function than defined

Tags: php, function, parameters, restriction

In php you can usually call a function with more parameters than have been defined, e.g.

```
function f($a, $b) {
     return $a . $b;
}
f('a', 'b', 'c', 'e');
```

is totally valid.

I understand that you can define functions with a variable number of parameters. But in most cases that is not what you want to do.
So in these cases if you mistakenly replace a `.` by a `,` you will not even get warning.

```
$x = '0';
f('a' , 'b' . $x . 'c') // returns ab0c
f('a' , 'b' , $x . 'c') // returns ab
```

Now in PHP 7 there is the `function f($a, $b, ...$others)` syntax. So in princable it is possible to discern variable parameter functions from ordinary ones.

Is there a way to get a notice when a function is called with too many parameters?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method of actually counting the variables sent to your function, however you can only do this INSIDE the function or BEFORE the function by counting the sent items.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php for more information.

You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php to GET the current arguments sent to the function.

Your issue would however need something like this:

```
function(){
    $count = func_num_args();
    if($count > 3){
        //too many args
    }
    else{
       //continue your actual code
    }
}
```